# Using multiple sequences in trigger to generate unique identity

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sequence

I am entering rows to my equipment table and if it is an antenna, I want to add prefix 'A' for antenna(antennas have foot number 1 to 4) and this prefix has a sequence for numbering.
Also if it is not an antenna, it will take foot number -1 and have a prefix starts with 'E' for equipments.

*Using ORACLE db.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AFM.INV_SEQ_EQ_TOY_T
BEFORE INSERT ON AFM.EQ
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.antenna_foot_number in (-1,1,2,3,4))
BEGIN
    IF :new.antenna_foot_number = -1 THEN
        :new.eq_id := 'E'|| INV_SEQ_EQ_TOY.nextval;
    else :new.eq_id := 'A'|| INV_SEQ_EQ_ANTENNA_TOY.nextval;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: There was a compile error when i run this script first time. thanks for correcting my question. I tried today, script run fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem ...

```
SQL> create table eq (antenna_foot_number number, eq_id varchar2(20))

Table created.

SQL> create sequence inv_seq_eq_toy;

Sequence created.

SQL> create sequence inv_seq_eq_antenna_toy;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger inv_seq_eq_toy_t
  2    before insert on eq
  3    referencing new as new old as old
  4  for each row
  5    when (new.antenna_foot_number in (-1,1,2,3,4))
  6  begin
  7      if :new.antenna_foot_number = -1 then
  8         :new.eq_id := 'E'|| inv_seq_eq_toy.nextval;
  9      else
 10         :new.eq_id := 'A'|| inv_seq_eq_antenna_toy.nextval;
 11      end if;
 12  end;
 13  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into eq(antenna_foot_number) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into eq(antenna_foot_number) values (-1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from eq;

ANTENNA_FOOT_NUMBER EQ_ID
------------------- --------------------
                  1 A1
                 -1 E1

SQL>
```

Were you just bragging that you managed to create a trigger as you wanted? If so, well, you succeeded.

Comment: referencing new as new old as old can be removed

Comment: I know, @Kaushik. I left it intentionally, to show that code - without any changes - works OK.